# Set 'Do Until' Endpoint for Excel VBA Macro Loop

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I know almost nothing about VBA and need some help! I've recorded a simple macro that will insert a row and perform some relative cut/paste when a certain value ("Choice") is found in column B. I would like this macro to loop until it reaches the end of the data set (keep in mind part of the macro inserts more rows as it goes). I've gotten it to loop and do what I want, but I can't figure out how to make it stop and not be infinite. Searching for blanks will not help as there are several blanks within the data set. Hoping for a helpful Do Until code?  If you have a solution, can you please append it to my macro in your reply so I can see how the whole thing would look? Thank You!!

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
' Spacer
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Dim c As Range

   For Each c In Range("B1:B3000")
    Cells.Find(What:="choice", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:B1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
' Spacer
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
Dim c As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For I = lastRow To 1 Step -1

        Debug.Print .Cells(I, 2).Value
        If InStr(1, .Cells(I, 2).Value, "choice") > 0 Then

            .Cells(I, 2).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:B1").Select
            Selection.Cut
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

        End If

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

When I run this code against this input ...

[image]

I get this output ...

[image]

Is this the result you were looking for? If not, can you provide a better description of the result you need?

Comment: Hmmm, that one doesn't seem to do anything. Cursor doesn't even move.

Comment: Whenever "choice" occurs in column B, insert a row above, and then move the values from columns A and B up one row into the new row

Comment: `move the values from columns A and B up one row into the new row` the values from the row where choice occured? New row meaning the one just inserted?

Comment: Hmm, still nothing. I don't get an error message, it just doesn't do anything.  Again, I know nothing about VBA, but just wondering- why are we calling Dim c as Range if we don't use it in the rest of the code?  Appreciating your help!

Comment: Is the sheet in question active? Does column B contain "choice"? Yea we don't need `c`. Forgot about it XD

Comment: It's the only workbook/worksheet I have open, so I would imagine it is. Yes, column B does contain a few dozen choice entries

Comment: Beats me then :/ Works for me. Edit: are we looking for `choice` or `Choice` or both?

Comment: Ummmmm, yep it was a case issue! We were looking for Choice, didn't know it made a difference because in my original macro (which used the Excel Find function), of course it ignores case, so being a newbie I didn't think it mattered in VBA.  Thanks guys!!

Comment: in the top of your module, `Option Compare Text` should make the `InStr` function [insensitive to case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t3khw5f.aspx).